# How to return 3 closest locations from to users location using jQuery or JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, sqlite, jquery-mobile

In my mobile app, I've got users geolocation using the following code. I also have a geolocaion (latitude, longitude) of nearby cities. I can put the geolocation data of cities in array or SQLite database. How do I get and display the 3 closest cities near the users location using jQuery or JavaScript. I'm not using Google Maps.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var Geo={};

    if (navigator.geolocation) {
       navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, error);
    }

    //Get the latitude and the longitude;
    function success(position) {
        Geo.lat = position.coords.latitude;
        Geo.lng = position.coords.longitude;
    }

    function error(){
        console.log("Geocoder failed");
    }

    function populateHeader(lat, lng){
        $('#myPopup').append('<p>Lattitude: ' + lat);
        $('#myPopup').append('<br />Longitude: ' + lng + '</p>');
    }
});
```

Thanks

Joe

Answer (score 0):

A simple google search resulted in this javascript code to calculate distance between two points.

```
var R = 6371000; // metres
var φ1 = lat1.toRadians();
var φ2 = lat2.toRadians();
var Δφ = (lat2-lat1).toRadians();
var Δλ = (lon2-lon1).toRadians();

var a = Math.sin(Δφ/2) * Math.sin(Δφ/2) +
        Math.cos(φ1) * Math.cos(φ2) *
        Math.sin(Δλ/2) * Math.sin(Δλ/2);
var c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1-a));

var d = R * c;
```

More explanation [here](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html).
You may have to find the value of `d` for each city and the geo location point.

Comment: What is d? Is it the distance in KM or meters?

Comment: sorry for the delay. d is in metres.